# font awesome icon not displaying in custom module joomla

Tags: font-awesome, joomla3.0, joomla-module

i want to display font awesome icon in custom joomla module, but when i write  tag and saves the code, it doesn't displays any icon. when i write the same code in php file, it works.
following is the code:

```html
<i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-4x " aria-hidden="true"></i>
<h4>
  Very fast &amp; easy
</h4>
<p>
    lorem ipsum
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer. In global configurations, set default editor to none.It works :)

Answer (score 0):

no need to change editor, you can use TINYMCE editor default. this link may be help full to you:

https://www.joomla-monster.com/blog/joomla-3-0/how-to-stop-joomla-editor-from-cleaning-some-html-elements